# Non excited synchronous motor

Tags: motor, synchronous

I was looking for a synchronous motor for my rotary spark gap. On this page I found what I need. http://www.tb3.com/tesla/sparkgaps/1800srsg/1800srsg.html
But the motor model is not 100% same on the web page the motor is a (SHINANO TOKKI X7807-202V) and I have (SHINANO TOKKI X7807-015V) the guy is explaining how to determine if a motor is synchronous or not, with a fluorescent light and white plastic tube on the motor shaft (please visit the website so you understand what I mean) I don't have a fluorescent light lying around, so I can't determine if my motor is synchronous.

May question.
Is there other methods for determining if a motor is running synchronous.

Comment: Where did you buy the motor from?

Comment: White tape on the shaft, black line, make the motor spin, measure the RPM with a tachometer.

Comment: @rdtsc That will not tell you if it's synchronous, some motors have considerable slip.

Comment: @Andyaka I bought the motor on eBay,The seller has no idea of the motor specs or is it synchronous.

Comment: quando buying a ebay caveat emptor

Comment: A synchronous motor has [zero slip, by design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor). Er. go. if the measured RPM were 1748RPM (and the tachometer is accurate), then it is not running at a synchronous speed, so is not a synchronous motor. But I bet it will be exactly 1800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make yourself a simple strobe with a couple of LED that would work like a flouro tube.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBuYN9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 would need to be a 2W resistor, R1 a 1/4W
Di1 is a 7-9 volts DIAC [BSOD-T112](http://www.pwrx.com/pwrx/docs/bs08d.pdf) from Digikey

D1 and D2 could be any LED with a VF @ 20mA of around 2.2-2.6V. You probably can't use White LEDs.
The conduction angle for the LEDs should be about 45-50deg.

At 50Hz you get 100Hz strobes and at 60Hz you get 120Hz strobes.

Comment: You give me very nice idea, I decided to go with similar path, I was using a full bridge rectifier and use the ripple for my benefit the ripple is exactly 2 x input frequency.